# implementation of query in django: select title, earning from task where answer.title==task.title and answer.title=='T';

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 apps named "answer" and "task" and I want to pick the earning and title column from "task" model where `answer.accept_answer='T'`; so the query I want to implement is:

```
select title, earning from task where answer.title==task.title and answer.title=='T';
```

**task.models:**

```
class Task(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    earning = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6 , decimal_places=2) 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**answer.models:**

```
class answers(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    answer = models.URLField()
    ANSWER_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Declined'),
        ('T', 'Accepted'),
    )
    accept_answer = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ANSWER_CHOICES, default='f')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer
```

Answer (score 0):

well i figured it out but idont know if this way is more efficient or not.

**views.py**

```
def earning(request, username):
    instance = Profile.objects.get(username= request.user)
    context = {'profile':instance}
    c={}
    if instance.total_earning:
        t_m = answers.objects.filter(accept_answer = 'T', username = request.user)
        for t in t_m:
            m = Task.objects.get(title = t.title)
            c.update({'title':m.title,'earning':m.earning})


        context.update(c)
    else:
        context.update({'no':"no task completed"})
    print(context)

    return render(request, "earning.html", context)
```